# Setting HTML in a data attribute in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml, html-dataset

I can not figure it out that how is it possible to use HTML in a data attribute inside React's jsx.

Like

`data-bs-template='<div class="tooltip d-none d-md-block" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'`

Is this approach right or wrong?

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out how to do it? You just did it. What is the intended result?

Comment: You can try `data-bs-template={"<div class='...'>...</div>"}` or `data-bs-template={'<div class="...">...</div>'}` however with React there might be a better approach; why do you need to put HTML in a data attribute in the first place? That's already a bad idea in regular HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In order set HTML in a React component, you need to create an object that has the `__html` property and the a string that contains the relevant HTML markup. Like this:

```
{__html: '<span>Something</span>'};
```

And finally render it using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) which is React's replacement for the native [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
function Tooltip(props) {
  const someHTML = {
    __html: `<div class="tooltip d-none d-md-block" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">${props.text}</div></div>`
  };
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={someHTML}></div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Tooltip text="Hello this is a tooltip" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @juan-marco ! I was confused actually to use HTML for data-bs-template. Thanx for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass attribute like this:

data-bs-template={

```
"<div class="tooltip d-none d-md-block" role="tooltip">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
</div>"
```

}

**Updated Code**

Comment: This doesn't work; the inner React object gets force cast to a string and the dataset child ends up being literally `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Can try attribute value as a string. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

There is your answer:

```
const App = () => {
 const data = '<b>lorem ipsum</b>';

 return (
   <div
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
   />
 );
}

export default App;
```